# How do I stop rAlt+Spacebar from outputting the NO-BREAK SPACE character?

Tags: linux, keyboard, arch-linux, xorg, input

I use a non-English keyboard layout, which contains multiple characters that have to be input using, for example, <kbd>rAlt</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, and I frequently press <kbd>rAlt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> by accident, inserting an unicode character where I really don't want it. Worse, I often don't even realize I've done it until later, and something breaks.

How can I remap <kbd>rAlt</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> to just output a standard ASCII space instead?

I use Manjaro Linux, Xfce, and X.Org. My keyboard layout is Polish.

Comment: see [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions), take `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/pl` and search for _space_